# Compass Susy error undefined variable.

Tags: ruby, sass

I formatted my Macbook Pro and now I'm having problems with susy. When I'm trying to compile my sass-file, it gives an error "error sass/screen.scss (Line 25 of _support.scss: Undefined variable: "$experimental-support-for-mozilla".)"

How can I fix this?

susy 1.0.9
ruby 2.1.0
compass 0.12.1
sass 3.2.13

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's a Compass setting. Either Compass isn't being imported properly, or you need a different version.

Answer (score 7):

You may need to add a Gemfile (and lock) it with Bundler to specify your gem versions. See http://bundler.io for more info. Also mentioned on the susy website: http://susy.oddbird.net/guides/getting-started/#troubleshooting-versions

See if adding

```
@import "compass";
```

at the start of screen.scss doesn't solve it.

Comment: That import statement fixed an error I had. On OS X 10.7 with who knows what ruby etc setup this was not needed. But added the above @import when moving to new 10.9 Mac and fixed this error: [Undefined variable: "$experimental-support-for-mozilla".)]. So thanks ^_^

Comment: I already have `@import "compass";` at the top of my file.  Still get the error `Error: Undefined variable: \"$experimental-support-for-mozilla\`

Comment: maybe start by updating compass and susy?

Answer (score 0):

@user3288198 In my case it was issue with runing on compass 1.0.0 insted of 0.12.7

So i had to lock specific version of compass in `Gemfile` for http://bundler.io

```
gem 'susy', '1.0.8'
gem 'compass', '0.12.7'
```